# Cakephp inflector library dosen't load

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have a very strange problem. The following code is worked fine in localhost but when i move it to my VPS inflector class seems to be not load. Note cakephp version in both localhost and VPS are 1.3.0.

```
<?php foreach ($tours as $tour): ?>
<li class="liboxs">
<?php echo $html->image('B0001WS6L2.jpg', array('url' => array('controller' => 'tours', 'action' => 'view', $tour['Tour']['id'], Inflector::slug($tour['Tour']['title'], '-')), 'alt' => $tour['Tour']['title'])) ?>
<ul>
  <li class="title"><?php echo $tour['Tour']['title'] ?></li>
  <li class="des"><?php echo $tour['Tour']['origin'] ?> » <?php echo $tour['Tour']['destination'] ?></li>
  <li class="day"><?php echo $tour['Tour']['stay_long'] ?> روز</li>
  <li class="price"><?php echo $tour['Tour']['price'] ?> تومان</li>
</ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

edit:
so, where is the problem? $html->image should produces example.com/tour/1/seo-friendly-url which it does in localhost but in in vps it produces example.com/tour/1

Comment: Are you sure the .htaccess files and mod_rewrite are on?

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistake? its pretty much impossible for cake to work with out the Inflector and its included with a 'require' meaning php would die if it was not there

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/bootstrap.php#L34

what is the *exact* error you are being shown.

Side note, 1.3.9 was released yesterday... time to upgrade?

Comment: i got no error. the link produce above should be example.com/tour/1/seo-friendly-url but in VPS it produces example.com/tour/1

Comment: that is not an inflector problem, maybe your variable is empty